# Center and hide specific-width side-by-side elements inside a specific-width parent

Tags: html, css

I have a Parent element with specified width. Inside it there are some Children elements, their width is also set (using percents).

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.parent{
    width:1000px;
}
.child{
    width:33.33%;
}
```

I want to:

1. Make the Children centered, if they don't occupy the whole parent's width (or wrap to next lines).
2. At the same time, if any of the Children doesn't have any content - hide it, so that its siblings act as if it doesn't exist.

What I can think of so far. The first can be done giving the Children `display: inline-block;`. But - this way they can only be hidden, if they're literally totally empty, with `.child:empty {display :none;}`; any whitespace kills the effect.

On the other hand, there are floats. If I float the Children and give them `min-height: 0;`, this hiding technique will ignore whitespaces since (as the Spec says)

> floats with zero outer height or negative outer height do not shorten line boxes.

But because the Parent has fixed width, I have no idea how to center the structure.

And I don't want to use JavaScript. Is it possible at all?

Thanks!

Comment: That's some pretty tough criteria.. Your solution with `:empty` seems like the best bet; why would the children with no other content have whitespace? Can't that be removed?

Comment: @Blake I want to consider some WYSIWYG editors' ugly actions, as well as content managers', since the markup is going to be used in CMS templates.